# Kivy browse a list on button click

Tags: android, python, ios, listview, kivy

In Kivy, is there a way to browse items of a list or array one by one. I can loop through a list but i want each item to display only after clicking the button. I need this because i want to create profile pages for my user pages but they can only be viewable upon clicking the button one at a time

Here is a little example:

```
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button

mylist = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']

def myfunction(self):
    print('some function logic needs to go here to display one item upon clicking the button')

class MainView(ListView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainView, self).__init__(
            item_strings=[str(x) for x in mylist])

        self.add_widget(Button(text='press', size_hint=(1, .05), on_press=myfunction))

runTouchApp(MainView())

# in pure python, i just want to display the following items one by one upon clicking the button
mylist = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']

i = 0
for x in mylist:
    print(mylist[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: So after days of struggling, i found something called the input('waiting...') option. I will look into using it and feedback. Right now feel free to give more more options. Thanks

Comment: Where do you want the text to appear? In a Label, in a TextEdit, etc? On the other hand, what should happen when the last item is reached and the button is pressed? nothing, return to the beginning of the list, ...?